# Comparing two Sqlalchemy Table Objects with Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, object

I am trying to see if two table objects match, and have found documentation regarding Python's `__eq__` function but am unsure how to use it with my code.  Here is the code I'm testing:

```
def get_table(self, table_name, select_stmt=None):
    """
        This method gets a table from the data connection using SQLAlchemy's reflection capability. Columns in the
        select_stmt are included, with all other table columns excluded.
        :param table_name: The name of the table being reflected.
        :type table_name: str
        :param select_stmt: The fields being included in the query. Default None.
        :type select_stmt:  str
        :returns:  SQLAlchemy Table object
    """
    table = Table(table_name, self.meta)
    self.log.debug("Reflecting table %s" % table_name)

    if select_stmt == "all_columns":
        select_stmt = None

    self.insp.reflecttable(table, select_stmt)

    return table
```

My test currently looks like:

```
    def test_select_all_data_no_columns(self):
    # Testing that when all columns are selected, None value is passed.
    given_result = DataConnector(self.source).get_table(self.table, "all_columns")
    expected_result = DataConnector(self.source).get_table(self.table)

    self.assertEquals(given_result, expected_result)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing implementation details but it looks like you are testing `get_tables` with the function itself.  Generally you want to separate out the functionality you want to test from a function and independently verify that.  A good way to do this is to have a test database where you know the data in it, and then given this knowledge test if the function returns the right thing likely by ensuring all the entries are correct.

Comment: I'm testing similar functionality for get_tables.  In one I am specifically passing the option "all_columns".  In the other, I'm not passing the option.  I have other tests that verify the function is returning the object properly.  I want to ensure that I get the same results between the two tested options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered how to do this.  The problem is that the results were also returning object values that were not matching.  By changing the test to

```
self.assertCountEqual(given_result.columns._data, expected_result.columns._data)
```

I was able to get the table structure I needed to verify.